# Update another table from the resultset of a query

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, count, sql-update

```
select 
(SELECT count(ts.student_id) AS studentcount
from tb_student ts
where  ts.tudent_id>101 )as count1,
(SELECT count(tt.teacher_id) AS Totalteacher from tb_teacher tt
 where feedback_id<>0) as count2
```

This gives me some result

```
count1   count2
 4         9
```

In some cases the count will be equal like

```
 count1   count2
 9         9
```

I need to update another table using this result, like when `count1=count2`
 then update a table called `tb_log` and set      `falg=1`

Can it be done within this query apart from doing it through procedure.

Comment: Are you updating a record in the tb_log table?  If so what do you match on?  Or are you inserting a record into that table?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done quite easily:

```
update tb_log
    set falg = 1
    where exists (select count1, count2
                  from (SELECT count(ts.student_id) AS studentcount
                        from tb_student ts
                        where  ts.tudent_id>101
                       ) as count1 cross join
                       (SELECT count(tt.teacher_id) AS Totalteacher
                        from tb_teacher tt
                        where feedback_id<>0
                       ) as count2
                  where count1 = count2
                 )
```

I moved your subqueries from the SELECT clause into the FROM clause.  I think queries are easier to follow when table references are in the FROM clause.  This also makes it easier to apply the condition in the WHERE clause.

Comment: This looks good.  Just note Mdharmendra that this will update all records in the tb_log table.  If you want to update a specific row you will need a join or additional where condition.

Comment: I could not understand what cross join will do here?